# how to change this embed?

Tags: javascript, discord, embed, leaderboard

Hiiii! So after many days im finally close to finishing my "currency bot". One of the last parts is the leaderboard, and it's working. but, I don't like how it looks but I don't know how to change it. It might sound confusing so I'm just gonna put some screenshots to make it clear

[image: 1]]

This is the message I'm getting but I want the number to be in the same line as the user and number:

1. @Pegasus BOT - 100000
2. @wex - 11000
3. @wextest - 2000

Here's part of the code I'm using:

```
const topembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#FF3A0E')
.setTitle(message.guild.name + "'s TOP Donators!")
.setTimestamp()

if(res.length === 0) {
    topembed.addField(`No data found`)
} else if(res.length < 10) {
    for(i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let member = res[i].userID
            topembed.addField(`${i + 1}`, `${member} **- ${res[i].donos}**`,)
```

I use MongoDB to save data if it matters

**Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\n` to begin a new line. Maybe description might be more suitable.

```js
var description = ""
for(i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  let member = res[i].userID
  description += `${i + 1}. ${member} **- ${res[i].donos}**\n`
}
topembed.setDescription(description)
```

Comment: now it returns with a lowest ```donos``` score and nothing else :/

Comment: Chindanonda my bad. your code works perfectly i just didn’t notice that you defined description, so i just did bar description; before. Now it works without any problem. Thank!!